# Many string replacements in R

Tags: r, string

How can I do a string replace for one column, but multiple conditions.

I have the following data

```
strings <- as_tibble(c("string.a","string.a", "string.b", "string.c"))

# A tibble: 4 x 1
  value       
  <chr>       
1 string_alice
2 string_alice
3 string_bob  
4 string_joe
```

and the following replacements

```
replacements <- c("alice", "bob", "joe")
conditions <- c(".a", ".b", ".c")
```

The resulting data would be

```
result <- as_tibble(c("string_alice", "string_bob", "string_joe"))

# A tibble: 4 x 1
  value       
  <chr>       
1 string_alice
2 string_alice
3 string_bob  
4 string_joe
```

I have considered a mapping table of some sort, but it is not clear to me how to feed a mapping table to a string replace function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nm = setNames(replacements, gsub("\\.", "", conditions))
sapply(strsplit(strings$value, "\\."), function(x){
    paste(c(x[1], nm[x[2]]), collapse = ".")
})
```

Data

```
strings = structure(list(value = c("string.a", "string.a", "string.b", 
"string.c")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
sub("\\.", "_",  gsubfn("(\\w+)$", setNames(as.list(replacements), 
       sub("\\.", "", conditions)), strings$value))  
#[1] "string_alice" "string_alice" "string_bob"   "string_joe"
```